# How to create a new object, passing it some parameters, and then saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a new object, passing it some initial values, and then saving to the db and return the saved object.

how can I do this?

example:

1. create a new user object
2. initiaze the user.user_age property to 35
3. save and return the saved object b/c I need access to the user.user_id value.

What's the ruby way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user = User.create(:user_age => 35)
```

This will initialize a new object, set the `user_age` attribute to 35, save it to the database and return the `User` object which represents that record in the database.

Comment: thanks, any tips on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056816/how-can-i-set-the-default-for-a-column-as-a-guid